# maven-eclipse-plugin: how to force to use a jar dependency rather than project dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, build, maven-3

Encountered a problem when using maven's Eclipse plugin. In the same workspace, there are two projects, **A and B**.
Project A will be provided as a jar to a 3rd-party and Project B was created to simulate the scene to use A. So definitely I want jar dependency in B rather than project dependency.
In B's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

As `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` executed successfully on B, I always got project dependency. The workaround is to modify .classpath file, or just copy B to another workspace, but both is inconvenient.

*maven 3.0.2; eclipse 3.7 without m2eclipse*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the maven-eclipse-plugin's useProjectResources to false. This way the project should only use jar dependencies directly and not reference any projects.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Declipse.useProjectReferences=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling workspace resolution (right click `project B`, Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution).  If you want a more sure way, simply closing project A in Eclipse is sufficient.

Comment: I use eclipse without m2eclipse, so eclipse really has nothing to do with this problem. Closing project doesn't help either.

Comment: Sorry, I saw "maven's Eclipse plugin" and thought you meant m2e.  My advice isn't particularly helpful then, but I'll leave it in case someone finds this later :)